# Elasticsearch on EKS: Running <elasticsearch-keystore> etc commands from kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-s3, kibana, amazon-eks

When we want to take a snapshot to S3 bucket, we have to enter the s3.client.default.access_key and s3.client.default.secret_key to every master and data node of the cluster. This is done by me now, entering in command line of every pod and giving the corresponding commands:

```
elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.access_key
elasticsearch-keystore add s3.client.default.secret_key
```

After that, we have to reload the secure settings in kibana and continue with the snapshot running on dev tools:

`POST _nodes/reload_secure_settings`

The first step especially when nodes (pods) are multiple and replaced or changing in EKS, can be annoying. Is there any way to run the first 2 commands in kibana and enter the access key and secret access key from there to all nodes?

I've found nothing about this in a search in web. I was hopping to find a way to simplify the process.

Comment: You should be able to specify that in [Kubernetes secrets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-es-secure-settings.html) or there are also [other](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/kubernetes-backup-restore-elasticsearch-717-s3-itgixltd/) [ways](https://raphaeldelio.medium.com/how-to-backup-elasticsearch-on-kubernetes-with-amazon-s3-and-kibana-b282771e4da2) to do it